# How can one silently test for the existence of documentation for a given Message tag?

Tags: documentation, hyperlink

**Background:**

A hyperlink to Wolfram documentation is easily accomplished using paclet links (e.g., `Hyperlink["Plot", "paclet:ref/Plot"]`). This works as well for the documentation of `Message` tags, as demonstrated by the information link ("***i***" in a blue disk) at the end of a displayed message, and by the tag's entry in the accompanying popup menu.

Separate documentation does not exist for all message tags (e.g., `FileByteCount::fdnfnd`), so when such messages are generated, the standard message display shows no information link (thereby avoiding a "**Why the Beep?**" dialog), and the popup menu instead links directly to the symbol's documentation.

For this to work, there must be some way to test *before* message display whether a documentation page exists for the message tag.

**My question:**

I would like to emulate this behavior by redirecting hyperlinks to symbol documentation when there is no separate documentation for a symbol's message tag.  However, I've been unable to find a way to silently test for the existence of a documentation page for a tag.  Is this possible?

**Motive**

Messages generated by tasks aren't captured for the "MessageGenerated" handler function (a bug confirmed by Wolfram tech support — Mac version 13.3 in my case). Therefore, I've been intercepting messages via an alternate `Message` handler. Displaying the message isn't as straightforward as just repeating it though because the current stack needs to be captured too, and I've found no way to display the message with accompanying stack data without jury-rigging my own `Message` display function. I have everything working, except for a link to tag documentation *or symbol documentation*.